# How to sum up values from each child node into parent in JSON using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I receive a JSON from server which is fluid in structure. Which is a **chapter** has a **stage(s)** and/or **review-set** at root. If a stage exists for sure there will be a **review-set** array of object or **another stage**. The **review-set** contains 2 attributes which hold data.

Here is the sample JSON

```
    {
    "id": "chapter",
    "chapterName": "Example Chapter",
    "stages": [
        {
            "id": "stage",
            "stages": [
                {
                    "id": "stage",
                    "stages": [],
                    "reviewSets": [
                        {
                            "id":"reviewset-1",
                            "yettoanswer": 2,
                            "answered": 4
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
            "reviewSets": [
                {
                    "id": "reviewset-2",
                    "yettoanswer": 3,
                    "answered": 5
                },
                {
                    "id": "rewviewset-3",
                    "yettoanswer": 6,
                    "answered": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "stage",            
            "stages": [
                {
                    "id": "stage",
                    "stages": [],
                    "reviewSets": [
                        {
                            "id": "reviewset-4",
                            "yettoanswer": 0,
                            "answered": 8
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "reviewset-5",
                            "yettoanswer": 4,
                            "answered": 4
                        }                        
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "reviewSets": [
                {
                    "id": "reviewset-6",
                    "yettoanswer": 1,
                    "answered": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": "reviewset-7",
                    "yettoanswer": 6,
                    "answered": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "reviewSets": [
        {
            "id": "reviewset-8",
            "yettoanswer": 0,
            "answered": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "reviewset-9",
            "yettoanswer": 1,
            "answered": 2
        }
    ],
}
```

Notice, stages and review-sets are array of objects. It can be null, one object or multiple objects.

I want to get the count of "yettoanswer" and "answered" at each "stage" and at root. The result I am looking for is as below:

```
{
    "id": "chapter",
    "chapterName": "Example Chapter",
    "yettoanswer" : 22,
    "answered" : 31,
    "stages": [
        {
            "id": "stage",
            "yettoanswer" : 11,
            "answered" : 9,
            "stages": [
                {
                    "id": "stage",
                    "yettoanswer" : 2,
                    "answered" : 4,
                    "stages": [],
                    "reviewSets": [
                        {
                            "id":"reviewset-1",
                            "yettoanswer": 2,
                            "answered": 4
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
            "reviewSets": [
                {
                    "id": "reviewset-2",
                    "yettoanswer": 3,
                    "answered": 5
                },
                {
                    "id": "rewviewset-3",
                    "yettoanswer": 6,
                    "answered": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "stage",
            "yettoanswer":11,
            "answered":18,
            "stages": [
                {
                    "id": "stage",
                    "yettoanswer":4,
                    "answered" : 12,
                    "stages": [],
                    "reviewSets": [
                        {
                            "id": "reviewset-4",
                            "yettoanswer": 0,
                            "answered": 8
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "reviewset-5",
                            "yettoanswer": 4,
                            "answered": 4
                        }                        
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "reviewSets": [
                {
                    "id": "reviewset-6",
                    "yettoanswer": 1,
                    "answered": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": "reviewset-7",
                    "yettoanswer": 6,
                    "answered": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "reviewSets": [
        {
            "id": "reviewset-8",
            "yettoanswer": 0,
            "answered": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "reviewset-9",
            "yettoanswer": 1,
            "answered": 2
        }
    ],
}
```

I would like to achieve above using javascript.

Comment: why do you get only 22 with `yettoanswer`? it should be 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the relevant keys and build the sum of the sub levels. the assign to properties to the actual level.

```js
var object = { id: "chapter", chapterName: "Example Chapter", stages: [{ id: "stage", stages: [{ id: "stage", stages: [], reviewSets: [{ id: "reviewset-1", yettoanswer: 2, answered: 4 }], }], reviewSets: [{ id: "reviewset-2", yettoanswer: 3, answered: 5 }, { id: "rewviewset-3", yettoanswer: 6, answered: 0 }] }, { id: "stage", stages: [{ id: "stage", stages: [], reviewSets: [{ id: "reviewset-4", yettoanswer: 0, answered: 8 }, { id: "reviewset-5", yettoanswer: 4, answered: 4 }] }], reviewSets: [{ id: "reviewset-6", yettoanswer: 1, answered: 2 }, { id: "reviewset-7", yettoanswer: 6, answered: 4 }] }], reviewSets: [{ id: "reviewset-8", yettoanswer: 0, answered: 2 }, { id: "reviewset-9", yettoanswer: 1, answered: 2 }] };

[object].reduce(function sum(r, o) {
    var v = ['stages', 'reviewSets'].reduce(function (r, k) {
            return (o[k] || []).reduce(sum, r);
        }, { yettoanswer: 0, answered: 0 });

    Object.keys(r).forEach(function (k) {
        o[k] = (o[k] || 0) + v[k];
        r[k] += o[k];
    });
    return r;
}, { yettoanswer: 0, answered: 0 })

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome!!!, thank you Nina. You saved my day. As a follow-up, for each **stages* I want to sum **stages** and **reviewSets** by looking up its length. Can this be done in the same code snippet which you have posted? Thanks, again.

Comment: please add an example of the wanted length for both. what is the length, btw the depth of the tree?

Comment: hm, i see nothing.

Comment: Hi Nina, in reference to result JSON above, under each **"id":"stage"** attribute and at root, I want to insert 2 attributes **stagesCount** and **reviewSetsCount** . As **stages** and **reviewSets** can hold array of objects. w.r.t to length, I meant **reviewSets.length** or **stages.length** will return number of objects in array. I need to sum number of **stages** and **reviewSets** in the tree and at each **stage**. Please click on this link for detailed example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/og51fu0d/2/) . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Nina mentioned in the comment, you probably forgot to count the `yettoanswer`s of `reviewSet`s in root as there should be (by your logic) 23, and not 22.

```js
var root = JSON.parse('{ "id": "chapter", "chapterName": "Example Chapter", "stages": [{ "id": "stage", "stages": [{ "id": "stage", "stages": [], "reviewSets": [{ "id": "reviewset-1", "yettoanswer": 2, "answered": 4 }] }], "reviewSets": [{ "id": "reviewset-2", "yettoanswer": 3, "answered": 5 }, { "id": "rewviewset-3", "yettoanswer": 6, "answered": 0 }] }, { "id": "stage", "stages": [{ "id": "stage", "stages": [], "reviewSets": [{ "id": "reviewset-4", "yettoanswer": 0, "answered": 8 }, { "id": "reviewset-5", "yettoanswer": 4, "answered": 4 }] }], "reviewSets": [{ "id": "reviewset-6", "yettoanswer": 1, "answered": 2 }, { "id": "reviewset-7", "yettoanswer": 6, "answered": 4 }] }], "reviewSets": [{ "id": "reviewset-8", "yettoanswer": 0, "answered": 2 }, { "id": "reviewset-9", "yettoanswer": 1, "answered": 2 }] }');
sumAnswers(root);
console.log(root); // `JSON.stringify(root)` if you need a JSON result

function sumAnswers(stage) {
  // introduce new properties to the current stage
  stage.yettoanswer = 0;
  stage.answered = 0;
  // sum up the values of reviewSets
  stage.reviewSets.forEach(function(child) {
    stage.yettoanswer += child.yettoanswer;
    stage.answered += child.answered;
  });
  // call this function for each stage and then
  // sum up the values of stages
  stage.stages.forEach(function(child) {
    sumAnswers(child);
    stage.yettoanswer += child.yettoanswer;
    stage.answered += child.answered;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @changed. Your approach too is good. Nina, indeed had counts at the root.

Comment: My solution has them too, they are just displayed on bottom... Properties are unordered.

Comment: I agree @changed. I am trying to learn from both of these solutions. Thank you.